# Effective use of ThreadPoolExecutor in Django views

Tags: python, django, multithreading

My goal is to offload some long running tasks to asynchronous threads using `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The task is triggered as part of a Django view, but the work doesn't seem to be happening asynchronously (the response hangs for like 10 seconds, i.e. the whole task completes before returning). Do I actually have to put the `ThreadPoolExecutor` code in the view? Why? Shouldn't I be able to do this (my current approach):

```
class SomeDjangoView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template_and_that.html'

    def get(self, request):
        clever_async_function()
        return render(request, self.template_name)

# Some other file
def clever_async_function():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(long_running_task, iterable_models_or_similar)
```

I'm aware that if it's really complicated I should setup something like Celery, but I'm trying to keep things lightweight for the moment.